# Unable to resolve host using curl/wget while page loads in browser

Tags: mac, wget, curl

The problem I am facing is that while I open a link in my browser it loads quickly but whenever I try using the link in terminal with 
for e.g. curl -0 www.google.com     or
         wget www.google.com  , both of them says

```
     unable to resolve host address `www.google.com'
```

I have already crossed checked the url if I have done any sort of mistake while writing the url but everything is correct.

Can any one tell what the problem is?

Comment: This is a guess: Do you have a proxy enabled? Please research how to obtain this information for your browser.

Comment: Yes I do. My network goes through proxy. Tell me how can I bypass it for curl/wget??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the http proxy with command line.

> export http_proxy="http://theipofproxy:port"